# Lookup table with variable breakpoints

Tags: excel-formula

### BACKGROUND

Normally when I am dealing with tables to find values to work with the tables are nicely laid out with something like:

[image: Sample Table 1]

and I rearrange them to make my lookup life easier by converting the table to look like:

[image: Sample Table 2]

I toss in the extra column so that someone maintain the table in the future will have an easier time updating the table and formulas that refer to it.  The formula I was using to for the table above was:

```
=INDEX(C3:I5,MATCH(MIN(B7:B8),A3:A5,1),MATCH(MAX(B7:B8),C2:I2,1))
```

<sub>Where B7:B8 had the dimensions I was referring to.  Right now I am working with the assumption that large dimensions only come in set sizes.  I would need to incorporate an interpolation approach if permitted and any sizes were used.</sub>

---

### CURRENT ISSUE

Now I just came across a table that is making me really think about what is the best approach to the situation.  The initial table looks like:

```
d/b | Cs            | Kls
<=1 | -             | 1
>1  | <=10          | 1
>1  | >10 but <Ck   | 1-0.3*(Cs/Ck)^4
>1  | >=Ck          | (0.70*E05)/Cs^2*fbu)
```

and my first go round at rearranging the table is:

```
d/b         | Cs                | Kls
0   | 1     | 0     | 0         | 1
1   | 1     | 0     | 10        | 1
1   | 1     | 10    | Ck        | 1-0.3*(Cs/Ck)^4
1   | 1     | Ck    | 9.99E+101 | (0.70*E05)/Cs^2*fbu)
```

So my two stumbling blocks is d/b can be any positive number 1.00001 or 0.99999 type deal.  so the d/b lookup has me a bit concerned only for the moment as in the background example the first column I am checking against is >= values.

The second stumbling block I have is that the breakpoint for the second lookup value Cs has a variable for two of the break point ranges.  The approach I was planning on taking here was simply calculate the value and pass it to the table when I go to do the look up. Now this approach works great for me when there is only one item to check.  This approach I do not think will work when I have to deal with multiple items to check.  Right now the only things I can think of are:

- Each item would require its own table...which kind of defeats the purpose of the table.
- convert the table to a nested IF function.

Its been a long day for me and the mind is a bit fried.  I am wondering if anyone would care to share their insight on the approaches I am thinking of or has an approach of their own for a table with a variable as a break point?

Ahh fiddle sticks!  I just reread the question and I never stated I was trying to pull the formula/result from the third column (ie Kls).  Told you mind was fried.

If I wind up going the nested if route I would use something like:

```
=IF(OR(E50<=1,E57<=10),1,IF(E57<E63,1-0.3*(E57/E63)^4,0.7*G63/(E57^2*D71)))

Where

 - E50 is b/d
 - E57 is Cs
 - E63 is Ck
 - G65 is E05
 - D71 is fbu
```

Comment: It will be helpful to give exact solution, if you attach your sample file with expected result somewhere in the web and provide us the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think a nested-IF would be better than rearranging the tables. You are losing some values by rearranging the cutoffs.
In your first example, the smaller dimension has >64 but <114.

When you change that, you have 0 to 64, 65 to 114. What about 64.5? This value is not part of your table. Nested IF statements would allow you to keep the original values of the table. Also, you can use a named range for variables which are the breakpoint for the second lookup value Cs.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying with the missing information in respect to current issue.  as for the background example, the nearest unit of measure is 1 mm, so you will not have the 64.5 case.  hence why I can cheat on that one in a sense.